# searching lucene index on multiple fields

Tags: lucene, query-parser

I have an index with 2 content fields (analyzed, indexed & stored):
for example: `name` , `hobbies`.  (The hobbies field can be added multiple times with different values).

I have another field that is only indexed (un_analyzed & not stored) used for filtering:
for example: `country_code`

Now, I want to build a query that will retrieve documents that match (as best as possible) to some "search" input field but only such documents where `country_code` has some exact value.

What would be the most suitable combination query syntax / query parser to use to build such a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
country_code:india +(name:search_value OR hobbies:search_value)
```

Comment: thanks,that was what I needed. I also added another + at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you start with `QueryParser`, it might work for your use case and it requires the least amount of effort.

It's not clear from your question, but let's assume you have a single input field ('search') and a combobox for the country code. You would then read those values and create a query:

```
// you don't have to use two parsers, you can do this using one.
QueryParser nameParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "name", your_analyzer);
QueryParser hobbiesParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "hobbies", your_analyzer);

BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(nameParser.parser(query), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
q.add(hobbiesParser.parser(query), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

/* Filtering by country code can be done using a BooleanQuery 
 * or a filter, the difference will be how Lucene scores matches. 
 * For example, using a filter:
 */
Filter countryCodeFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(new TermQuery(new Term("country_code", )));

//and finally searching:
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(q, countryCodeFilter, 10);
```

Comment: Can you add more information re what you said about the two filtering alternatives? how would it effect scoring? and what about performance ?

Comment: that sounds like another stackoverflow question :)